# Laravel orderByRaw array of user ID with binding

Tags: php, laravel, sql-injection

So, with my server, there's a scenario where I want to pass an array of ID to my Laravel server to fetch a list of users. At the same time, I want the returned database query results to also maintain the same order as the array of ID params I passed in.

I have the following which currently works:

```
$strIDs = $request->input('user_ids');
$u_ids = explode(",",$strIDs);
$users = User::whereIn('user_id',$u_ids)->notDeleted()->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(user_id, $strIDs)"))->get();
```

But I understand there's something called SQL Injection Attack and a recommended thing to do is bind the parameters of a SQL statement with variables to guard against these problems.

Following some other searches, I tried the following but the syntax is incorrect:

```
$users = User::whereIn('user_id',$u_ids)->notDeleted()->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(user_id, ':values')", ['values' => $strIDs]))->get();
```

Can anybody see what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the laravel 5, try to use the `orderBy`

The orderBy has a parameter to choose the Descend vs Ascendent, in your case, you should use:

```
$users = User::whereIn('user_id',$u_ids)->notDeleted()->orderBy('user_id', 'ASC')->get();
```

#### Example

Your input is: `[13,87,29]`

If you use the **ASC** `->orderBy('user_id', 'ASC')`
The output will be: `[13,29,87]`

If you use the **DESC** `->orderBy('user_id', 'DESC')`
The output will be: `[87,29,13]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll need to try it out this solution at my office tomorrow (IP blocked outside my office at the moment :P). Looks promising though :)

Comment: Joao, this doesn't do what I need. This one sorts the results by user_id from largest to smallest. What I need is for the result to be in the same order as the array of ids I passed in. E.g. if I pass in `[13,87,29]` I need the list of matching user records to be ordered `[13,87,29]` not `[87,29,13]`.

Comment: @Zhang I updated my answer, check if fill your needs

Comment: No, you're misunderstanding what I need. I am not trying to sort them from smallest to largest or from largest to smallest. I need them to be in the same order as the array of ID that I passed in. If I pass in `[13,87,29]`, then the array of user records returned should be `user with id 13, user with id 87, user with id 29` in that exact order.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent your application from sql injections indeed you should use prepared statements. And, there is no need of using Laravel raw queries as Laravel have internal function for these simple queries and will automatically do the preparing and binding for you.

Simply use:

```
$users = User::whereIn('user_id',$u_ids)->notDeleted()->orderBy('user_id')->get();
```

It will prevent your application from sql injections. Hope I have answered your question.

Comment: Did you just copy and pasted Joao Mantovani's answer?

Comment: Yes. I just thought that a little more explanation will be good and was unable to propose an edit due to privilege issue.

Comment: I can always delete it if there is no need of it (: